# Html empty right part

Tags: html

I am new to Html and css but I am stuck with a buggy problem. I created my first responsive website but when i scale it down to small sizes and scroll to the right there are 40-50 px of empty space with only the background . I must add that when I scale it up the empty part disappears. Some help?

```css
html {

    width:                  100%;
    display:                inline-block;
    margin:                 0px;
}

body {
     margin:                auto;
  font-family:           Arial;
  background-image:      url("weed.png");
     margin-left:           0px;
     margin-right:          0px;
}

 

/*Weedmania Logo*/

#weedmania_shade{
  z-index:               -1;
     height:                255px;
     width:                 100%;
     margin-left:           0px;
     margin-top:            0px;
     background-color:      rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

}

#weedmania_logo_img {
     margin-right:             -120px;
     margin-top:             -405px;
  height:                  370px;
     width:                   90%;
     min-width:               350px;
     max-width:               800px;
}



/*Site Banner*/

#site_panel {
     float:                left;
  background-image:     url(weeds.jpg);
  font-family:          "Gigi Regular";
  width:                98%;
  color:                green ;
  border:               4px solid black;
  padding:              5px;
     margin-left:          6px;
     margin-top:           -175px;
 }


#site_panel p {
     font-style:          italic;
     text-shadow:         1px 2px black;


}

#site_panel h1 {
     text-shadow:        1px 3px black;


}



/*Menu*/

nav {
  float:                 left;
     width:                 10%;
     max-width:             200px;
     min-width:             100px;
     height:                100px;
     margin-top:            0px;
     margin-left:           6px;
}

nav ul{
     padding:                       0;
     background-color:              green;
     border:                        2px solid black;
     
}

nav ul li {
     list-style:           none;
     border :              1px solid lime;
     padding :             5px;
}

nav ul li a{
  color:                 lime;
  list-style:            none;
  text-decoration:       none;
     font-family:           "Arial";
     font-style:            italic;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
     color :                #ccffb3;
     text-decoration:       underline;
}





/*Leaves And Joint*/

#joint_figure #joint_img{
     float:              center;
     border:             3px solid black;
     margin-top:         0px;
     width:              50%;
     min-width:          157px;


}



#leaf_img_left{

     float:                  left;
  max-width:              300px;
     width:                  25%;
     height:                 30%;
     margin-left:           -30px;
     margin-top:             10px;
    

}


#leaf_img_right{

     float:                  right;
     max-width:              300px;
     width:                  25%;
     height:                 30%;
     margin-right:          -30px;
     margin-top:             10px;

}


#description{

 
     width:              50%;
     height:             10%;
     min-width:          300px;
     font-size:          110%;
     background-color:   rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

}

#description_text{
      
     color:             rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
     font-family:       "Comic Sans MS";
     padding-top:       2px;
     text-align:        center;
     font-size:         83%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
     
     <title> WeedMania - Weed's biggest community </title>
     <link rel="stylesheet"   href="style.css">
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width"  contnet="initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>


<div><nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="file:///D:/Shits/Web/Joint/altjoint.html">Index</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="http://messywind.tumblr.com/">Good Trip</a> 
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/alex.bmx27">Buy Weed</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav></div>




<article><center><figure id="weedmania_shade"></figure></center></article>


          
<div><figure id="weedmania_logo"><center><img src="weedmania_logo.png" id="weedmania_logo_img" alt=""></center></figure></div>

<div><figure id="stop"></figure></div>


<div><article id="site_start">

    <header   id="site_panel"> 

    <h1> Smoke Weed Everyday </h1>
    <p> Posted by <strong>WeedMania</strong> </p>

    </header>


<div><figure class="leaves">

  <img id="leaf_img_left"   src="leaf.png"    alt="">
   
</figure></div>

<div><figure class="leaves">

  <img id="leaf_img_right"   src="leaf.png"    alt="">
   
</figure></div>

</article></div>

<div><center><figure id="joint_figure">


  <img id="joint_img"    src="joint1.jpg"     alt="">


</figure></center></div>


<center><article id="description">
  
<p id="description_text">This forum is designed to bring you the latest news about weed worldwide, informations about weed strains, smoking stories and , basically everything you need to know about weed. Feel free the create an account and join the community</p>

</article></center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give us an example? It could literally be anything. A character, an image, a div, padding, alignment...

Comment: It's like all the page is scaled to 90% and 10% is only wallpaper but when you scale it up the page is 100% and that 10% of empty space is filled

Comment: That's just as vague... post the offending code?

Comment: @Isaac, seems voting down is pointless if he's only got 1 rep

Comment: edit your question and hit CTRL + M and put all of your html, css, etc into the snippet box. There is no way in the world to just guess at your question with the lack of info you added

Comment: Done . Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want space to the right side. you need to remove 'min-width' or width with padding. Please see below example. you cannot have any spaces.

```css
html {

    width:                  100%;
    display:                inline-block;
    margin:                 0px;
}

body {
     margin:                auto;
  font-family:           Arial;
  background-image:      url("weed.png");
     margin-left:           0px;
     margin-right:          0px;
}

 

/*Weedmania Logo*/

#weedmania_shade{
  z-index:               -1;
     height:                255px;
     width:                 100%;
     margin-left:           0px;
     margin-top:            0px;
     background-color:      rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

}

#weedmania_logo_img {
     //margin-right:             -120px;
     margin-top:             -405px;
  height:                  370px;
     width:                   90%;
     //min-width:               350px;
     max-width:               800px;
}



/*Site Banner*/

#site_panel {
     float:                left;
  background-image:     url(weeds.jpg);
  font-family:          "Gigi Regular";
  //width:                98%;
  color:                green ;
  border:               4px solid black;
  padding:              5px;
     margin-left:          6px;
     margin-top:           -175px;
 }


#site_panel p {
     font-style:          italic;
     text-shadow:         1px 2px black;


}

#site_panel h1 {
     text-shadow:        1px 3px black;


}



/*Menu*/

nav {
  float:                 left;
     width:                 10%;
     max-width:             200px;
     min-width:             100px;
     height:                100px;
     margin-top:            0px;
     margin-left:           6px;
}

nav ul{
     padding:                       0;
     background-color:              green;
     border:                        2px solid black;
     
}

nav ul li {
     list-style:           none;
     border :              1px solid lime;
     padding :             5px;
}

nav ul li a{
  color:                 lime;
  list-style:            none;
  text-decoration:       none;
     font-family:           "Arial";
     font-style:            italic;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
     color :                #ccffb3;
     text-decoration:       underline;
}





/*Leaves And Joint*/

#joint_figure #joint_img{
     float:              center;
     border:             3px solid black;
     margin-top:         0px;
     width:              50%;
     //min-width:          157px;


}



#leaf_img_left{

     float:                  left;
  max-width:              300px;
     width:                  25%;
     height:                 30%;
     margin-left:           -30px;
     margin-top:             10px;
    

}


#leaf_img_right{

     float:                  right;
     max-width:              300px;
     width:                  25%;
     height:                 30%;
     margin-right:          -30px;
     margin-top:             10px;

}


#description{

 
     //width:              50%;
     height:             10%;
     //min-width:          300px;
     font-size:          110%;
     background-color:   rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

}

#description_text{
      
     color:             rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
     font-family:       "Comic Sans MS";
     padding-top:       2px;
     text-align:        center;
     font-size:         83%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
     
     <title> WeedMania - Weed's biggest community </title>
     <link rel="stylesheet"   href="style.css">
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

</head>
<body>


<div><nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="file:///D:/Shits/Web/Joint/altjoint.html">Index</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="http://messywind.tumblr.com/">Good Trip</a> 
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/alex.bmx27">Buy Weed</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav></div>




<article><center><figure id="weedmania_shade"></figure></center></article>


          
<div><figure id="weedmania_logo"><center><img src="weedmania_logo.png" id="weedmania_logo_img" alt=""></center></figure></div>

<div><figure id="stop"></figure></div>


<div><article id="site_start">

    <header   id="site_panel"> 

    <h1> Smoke Weed Everyday </h1>
    <p> Posted by <strong>WeedMania</strong> </p>

    </header>


<div><figure class="leaves">

  <img id="leaf_img_left"   src="leaf.png"    alt="">
   
</figure></div>

<div><figure class="leaves">

  <img id="leaf_img_right"   src="leaf.png"    alt="">
   
</figure></div>

</article></div>

<div><center><figure id="joint_figure">


  <img id="joint_img"    src="joint1.jpg"     alt="">


</figure></center></div>


<center><article id="description">
  
<p id="description_text">This forum is designed to bring you the latest news about weed worldwide, informations about weed strains, smoking stories and , basically everything you need to know about weed. Feel free the create an account and join the community</p>

</article></center>

</body>
</html>
```